# Python opposite of strip()

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out a function that does the opposite of strip for my Python class.

The exact question is:

What function can be used to surround a string with spaces in order to make it a certain length?

Thanks!

Comment: `'Hello, World!'.center(30)`.

Comment: Then this is not the opposite of strip. Maybe you should reformulate you question.

Comment: The question has been answered. Thank you.

Comment: Whether it's been answered or not it's not the opposite of strip.  The opposite of strip would return the outside chars of a string that matched the given char iterable handed to opposite_of_strip

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "opposite" of `strip` is the [`center`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.center) method:

```
>>> 'Hello, World!'.center(30)
'        Hello, World!         '
```

You can specify the fill character to use as second argument. The default is whitespace.

---

There are also [`ljust`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) and [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) that will left-justify and right-justify the text up to a certain length, and as such could be considered "opposites" of `lstrip` and `rstrip`.

Answer (score 2):

format strings

```
"%50s World"%("Hello") 
"%-50s World"%("Hello") 
"%^50s World"%("Hello")
```

or newfangled

```
"{0:50s} World".format("Hello")
"{0:>50s} World".format("Hello")
"{0:^50s} World".format("Hello")
```

these have nifty side effects

```
"%^*s World"%(50,"Hello")
```

Comment: I believe with `str.format` the correct characters for left/right align are `<` (same as none) and `>`. Using `-` gives `ValueError: Sign not allowed in string format specifier`

Comment: ahh thanks my bad (I usually use %)

Answer (score 0):

Try `s.center(N)` where `N` is the line length you want, `s` - your string.
For example:

```
>>> "xx".center(10)
'    xx    '
```